# policy-rate-limit "insert id" is not working

Tags: policyd

I installed policyd-rate-limit from ubuntu aptitude package manager
my distro is: ubuntu 22.04 server TLS on AWS
policy-rate-limit "version": 1.0.1.1-2
I provided mysql database details in configuration file I found in: `/etc/policyd-rate-limit.yaml`
and was sure mysql is selected in the variable `backend: 1`
then configured postfix (version 3.6.4-1ubuntu1.1) to use it as `smtpd_client_restriction`
I created a database according to "Rust" docs pages [here](https://docs.rs/crate/policyd-rate-limit/0.1.0) due to the sad lack of official documentation for `policy-rate-limit`
I sent a test email and `/var/log/syslog` has this:

```
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: connection from
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: request=smtpd_access_policy
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: protocol_state=RCPT
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: protocol_name=ESMTP
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: client_address=***.***.***.***
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: client_name=****************
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: client_port=27370
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: reverse_client_name=****************
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: server_address=***.***.***.***
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: server_port=587
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: helo_name=smtpclient.apple
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: sender=****************
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: recipient=****************
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: recipient_count=0
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: queue_id=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: instance=2300.64da7642.a2eda.0
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: size=0
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: etrn_domain=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: stress=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: sasl_method=PLAIN
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: sasl_username=****************
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: sasl_sender=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: ccert_subject=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: ccert_issuer=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: ccert_fingerprint=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: ccert_pubkey_fingerprint=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: encryption_protocol=TLSv1.2
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: encryption_cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: encryption_keysize=256
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: policy_context=
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: 000/010 hit since 60s
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: 000/150 hit since 86400s
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: insert id **********@my-domain.com
Aug 14 18:45:22 AWS-EC2 policyd-rate-limit[8782]: action=dunno
```

so I can see `insert id **********@my-domain.com` but when I go check the database, nothing is there as I expected!
I remembber when installing `policy-rate-limit`, I had also these lines:

```
Suggested packages:
  python3-mysqldb python3-psycopg2
...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/policyd_rate_limit/utils.py:88: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
self._config = yaml.load(f)
You need to install the python3 module MySQLdb to use the mysql backend
```

but the thing is am not using `policy-rate-limit` from python nor I installed it from pip. am using a standalone.
I don't want to set users limits from config files. I need mysql database for it. and installing mysql for python is so much troublesome, as I have python 3.10 from pyenv. and it has dependcy issue that can't be fixed using all workarounds I found

**UPDATE:**
I deleted the database table per Rust doc page.
I no longer get the missing mysql error when running `policyd-rate-limit --clean`
after following pip instructions `sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb`
I had to convert the file in `/var/lib/policyd-rate-limit/db.sqlite3` to mysql and run it, that created the correct database table needed called "mail_count".
I also temporarily enabled reporting in config file, and it also created another table called "limit_report"
now `--clean` flag runs like charm.
but still, the "insert" doesn't put anything in the database as I expect. (or are my expectations wrong ?)